# iOS HTTP Post method not working when key is not a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection

I am using Post method to send user data to server.

```
NSMutableArray *RegistraionKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"user[first_name]",@"user[last_name]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][date_of_birth]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][address]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][country]", @"user[user_profile_attributes][phone]", @"user[user_profile_attributes][gender]", nil];

NSMutableArray *RegistraionValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"GS", @"1987-07-19", @"bbb",@"IND", @"1234567890", @"male",nil];

NSDictionary *userRegistrationDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:RegistraionValues forKeys:RegistraionKeys];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userRegistrationDictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:method];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"en" forHTTPHeaderField:@"LOCALE"];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [sessionManager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSDictionary *results;
    if (data) {
        results =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }
}];
```

Here I have some keys like "user[first_name] , user[last_name] ..etc". If it is only "first_name" then I can pass this key as string. but "first_name" is under "user" so I have passed like "user[first_name]".

This code is not working and not update data into server. I want to know the correct way to pass the data if key is like this ("user[first_name]").

Note : "first_name" is under "user"

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show some sample of your request parameter

Comment: First two arrays (RegistraionKeys , RegistraionValues) are keys and paramaters.

Comment: its a wrong request, thats y I asked , if u show some sample request is easy to resolve else it takes too much of work

Comment: Really sorry that I did't get what you asked. I have given my all code here with values and parameters. and I have created NSMutableURLRequest with my own URL(http://myURL:223/api/v1/users).
.

Comment: ur url is not working bro, actually you generated the wrong ` NSMutableArray *RegistraionKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@`  in here

Comment: "userRegistrationDictionary" is having both keys and values . we have created this dictionary from those two array (RegistraionKeys , RegistraionValues) .

Comment: sorry bro, I can't help

Comment: And with this: `NSDictionary *userRegistrationDictionary = @{@"user":@{@"first_name":@"aaa", @"last_name":@"GS", @"user_profile_attributes":@{@"date_of_birth":@"1987-07-19", @"address":@"bbb", @"country":@"IND", @"phone":@"1234567890", @"gender":@"male"}}};`?

Comment: @Larme you saved my day King (Y). Thanks a lot

Comment: @Manimurugan If it works, can you validate the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
NSMutableArray *RegistraionKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"user[first_name]",@"user[last_name]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][date_of_birth]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][address]",@"user[user_profile_attributes][country]", @"user[user_profile_attributes][phone]", @"user[user_profile_attributes][gender]", nil];

NSMutableArray *RegistraionValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"GS", @"1987-07-19", @"bbb",@"IND", @"1234567890", @"male",nil];

NSDictionary *userRegistrationDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:RegistraionValues forKeys:RegistraionKeys];
```

I'll skip the fact that two var begins with a uppercase.

Well, if you read a little about JSON, or you're used, in Objective-C, to use short hand syntax (it exists in other languages too), you can assume that in fact, your web service is awaiting for something like that:

```
NSDictionary *userRegistrationDictionary = @{@"user":@{@"first_name":@"aaa",
                                                       @"last_name":@"GS",
                                                       @"user_profile_attributes":@{@"date_of_birth":@"1987-07-19",
                                                                                    @"address":@"bbb",
                                                                                    @"country":@"IND",
                                                                                    @"phone":@"1234567890",
                                                                                    @"gender":@"male"}}};
```

These are the results of the `userRegistrationDictionary` if you try then to convert it into JSON:

```
$>YourFirstVersion: {
  "user[user_profile_attributes][country]" : "IND",
  "user[user_profile_attributes][gender]" : "male",
  "user[first_name]" : "aaa",
  "user[last_name]" : "GS",
  "user[user_profile_attributes][date_of_birth]" : "1987-07-19",
  "user[user_profile_attributes][phone]" : "1234567890",
  "user[user_profile_attributes][address]" : "bbb"
}
$>CorrectVersion: {
  "user" : {
    "user_profile_attributes" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "phone" : "1234567890",
      "country" : "IND",
      "date_of_birth" : "1987-07-19",
      "address" : "bbb"
    },
    "first_name" : "aaa",
    "last_name" : "GS"
  }
}
```

Yours seems "weird". It's valid, but unusual. Everything is in the same level, but ZzZ[key] seems to look for a dictionary thing.